# how to setup local WiFi network in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wireless, home-directory, hot-spot

I would like to have local home network, so my PC, netbook can share files between each other. On both machines I have Ubuntu (latest versions).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, if your computer is having in-build wifi router or you have to use wifi dongle and also you have connected internet through ethernet.

1.Click the network connection icon at the top right corner.

2.Click on Edit connections then Network connection pop up window will open.

3 In Network connection window select wireless tap and click on "Use as hotspot".

4 If you want you can assaign name for your wifi network or you can use the default name.

5 Note down the pass key and enter the same with your devices you want to connect to wifi.

Answer (score 0):

For the hardware, you need wireless router (which recently usually contain modem and switch) and a computer for the server. For the software, you can use OpenVPN, Samba and Apache in which you will install in the server. The good tutorial on how to set up these free software in uBuntu is provided [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-intranet-with-openvpn-on-ubuntu-16-04). Once you set up, it would run as if you are connected to the internet through the server.