# It is possible create a Network LAN like in windows 7,8,10?

Tags: wireless, lan

I would like have a LAN network with my computers and devices like my cellphone and my laptops ,I was reach before that I do this question I saw that only :

[they said that we should use hotspot that I understoond](https://askubuntu.com/questions/317661/how-to-setup-local-wifi-network-in-ubuntu)

I was reatch in google and I found this tutorial for I make a network Lan : (I think this is the better option but I would like know that opinion of any expert in ubuntu here

[this tutorial](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-create-a-wireless-ad-hoc-network-in-ubuntu)

so I would like make a network LAN like in windows how is tutorial :
[tutorial](https://support.hp.com/id-en/document/c01894721)

I would like make thing how this:
[windows network LAN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PnVG.png) or [other example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kevBe.jpg)

I hope my question is no stupid but I am not expert in ubuntu and linux I hope can you help me

Comment: Are you asking how to share files across a LAN?

Comment: already I edited the post  with a explanation better

Comment: In what setting a corporate one or a home network? will the clients  be windows or linux (excluding the phone devices)

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in Ubuntu.

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and I use to connect other PCs running in windows using **samba**. It works well with earlier versions, but in 18.04 I find difficult to configure samba, as the windows hosts are not displayed. After some research, I've found that I have to install **samba client**. I use the following command:

```
sudo apt install smbclient
```

After running this, I am able to list the other hosts and  network and shares works well.

But in the case of cellphone, I don't know how to network with it. I usually transfer from cellphone, using direct cable connection, Bluetooth or by using apps like xender etc.

Comment: already I edited the post  with a explanation better